# how I can read a SEQUENCE and write it in text item?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Please help me!I dont know why i cant solve this simple problem.
I wanna read my sequence that I made it in my database and add it to my text Item.

any idea?(with code plz)

right know I write a cursor and call my sequence by a select from it but i dont know what should I do after it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Forms if you want to enter the value of a sequence into an item (named `:BLOCK.ITEM`) this would work:

```
SELECT your_sequence.nextval INTO :BLOCK.ITEM FROM DUAL;
```